# How to Load movie clip with a conditional dynamic text. IF...else

Tags: if-statement, load, conditional-statements, movie, clip

I have two dynamic texts, both of them are going to generate numbers. If one has a greater value then the other one, a movie clip must be loaded, else, another movie clip must  be loaded.

It's also important to note that I need to choose exactly the place that this movie clip will be load.

I create this code, but it's not working.

```
btn01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_27);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_27(event:MouseEvent):void
{


var texto.text;

function testGuess():void{

    if (parseInt(texto.text) == 8)


var fl_MyInstance_3:greenlight = new greenlight();
addChild(fl_MyInstance_3);          


    }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_on_Press);

function btn_on_Press(e:MouseEvent):void {

    var clp_index = parseInt(txt_01.text) > parseInt(txt_02.text) ? 1 : 2
    var new_clp = clp_index == 1 ? new clp_01() : new clp_02()

    // to set the new_clp position
    new_clp.x = 250   // left position
    new_clp.y = 50    // top position

    addChild(new_clp)

}
```

**Last Edit :**

```
stop()

var new_clp, new_clp2, new_clp3

var timer:Timer = new Timer(3000)
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer)
    timer.start()

function onTimer(evt:TimerEvent):void {

    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest('bdaily.txt'))
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event){
            bdaily.text = loader.data
        })

    var loader1:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest('bmtd.txt'))
        loader1.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event){
            bmtd.text = loader1.data
        })

    var loader2:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest('bwtd.txt'))
        loader2.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event){
            bwtd.text = loader2.data
        })

    var loader3:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest('basketdtarget.txt'))
        loader3.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event){
            basketdtarget.text = loader3.data
        })  

    var loader4:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest('basketwtdtarget.txt'))
        loader4.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event){
            basketwtdtarget.text = loader4.data
        })  

    var loader5:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest('basketmtdtarget.txt'))
        loader5.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event){
            basketmtdtarget.text = loader5.data
        })

    if(new_clp){
        new_clp.parent.removeChild(new_clp)
        new_clp = null
    }
    if(new_clp2){
        new_clp2.parent.removeChild(new_clp2)
        new_clp2 = null
    }
    if(new_clp3){
        new_clp3.parent.removeChild(new_clp3)
        new_clp3 = null
    }
    trace('new_clp : '+new_clp)
    trace('new_clp2 : '+new_clp2)
    trace('new_clp3 : '+new_clp3)

    var clp_index = parseInt(bdaily.text) >= parseInt(basketdtarget.text) ? 1 : 2
        new_clp = clp_index == 1 ? new clp_01() : new clp_02()
    addChild(new_clp)

    var clp_index2 = parseInt(bwtd.text) >= parseInt(basketwtdtarget.text) ? 1 : 2
        new_clp2 = clp_index2 == 1 ? new clp_03() : new clp_04()
    addChild(new_clp2)

    var clp_index3 = parseInt(bmtd.text) >= parseInt(basketmtdtarget.text) ? 1 : 2
        new_clp3 = clp_index3 == 1 ? new clp_05() : new clp_06()
    addChild(new_clp3)

}
```

This is the simplest way, you can optimize it later.

Comment: Worked perfectly! How can I control where the movie clip will be displayed?

Comment: I created a loop to check the info coming, the problem is that the movie clips keeping loading another movie clip in front of the other , that is using a lot of RAM. can you help me improve the code?

I need to unload all the info and do the if...else and load again.

Here is the code:

Comment: I created a loop to check the info coming, the problem is that the movie clips keeping loading another movie clip in front of the other , that is using a lot of RAM. can you help me improve the code? I need to unload all the info and do the if...else and load again

Comment: @d.Sierra Hi man, sorry because I was absent for many days, so can you explain me what do you want ?

Comment: Hi, no problem with that! You´ve been helping me a lot. Your code worked for me, the problem is I set a loop code to get .txt files every 5 seconds, and the movie clip (red light or green light signs) loads comparing the numbers in the dynamic text box. The problem is that the movie clips are beeing loaded one above the other and thar is consuming a lot of ram memory. I need to unload all movie clips and load them again.

Comment: To unload a movieclip, you can use `removeChild(mc)` and then assign a `null` value to it.

Comment: How can I do that? I tried this code:
removeChild(new_clp2);
Just inserted that on the last line of the code.

Comment: I used this command, but nothing happened.
function removeMC(e:Event):void {
 removeChild(clp_index);
}

Comment: @d.Sierra I edited my answer to show you how to remove all movie clips.

Comment: Thanks again, the fact is that i don't want to use a button to reset all process. I'm sending a link with a file attached. Please unzip all files in the same folder. I think it will be easier to understand. I'm trying to create a light comparison. But the code is looping the movie clip again and again... a lot of memory RAM consumption. download link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fqncg4uqf8590s7/AAAAl1wLbPS7Z9E0YmdletaVa?dl=0

Comment: @d.Sierra OK, I saw your code. Take a look, I added what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
stop();

// timer loading
var timer:Timer = new Timer(2500);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
    timer.start();

    function onTimer(evt:TimerEvent):void {
//primeiro indicador parte
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("bdaily.txt"));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
var loadedText:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
bdaily.text = loadedText.data;
}

// segundo indicador.
var loader1:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("bmtd.txt"));
loader1.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler1);

function completeHandler1(event:Event):void {
var loadedText1:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
bmtd.text = loadedText1.data;
}

//terceiro indicador
var loader2:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("bwtd.txt"));
loader2.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler2);

function completeHandler2(event:Event):void {
var loadedText2:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
bwtd.text = loadedText2.data;
}

//terceiro indicador
var loader3:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("basketdtarget.txt"));
loader3.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler3);

function completeHandler3(event:Event):void {
var loadedText3:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
basketdtarget.text = loadedText3.data;
}


var loader4:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("basketwtdtarget.txt"));
loader4.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler4);

function completeHandler4(event:Event):void {
var loadedText4:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
basketwtdtarget.text = loadedText4.data;
}


var loader5:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("basketmtdtarget.txt"));
loader5.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler5);

function completeHandler5(event:Event):void {
var loadedText5:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
basketmtdtarget.text = loadedText5.data;
}

//condicionais para gerar movieclip condicional
var clp_index = parseInt(bdaily.text) >= parseInt(basketdtarget.text) ? 1 : 2
    var new_clp = clp_index == 1 ? new clp_01() : new clp_02()
    addChild(new_clp)

var clp_index2 = parseInt(bwtd.text) >= parseInt(basketwtdtarget.text) ? 1 : 2
    var new_clp2 = clp_index2 == 1 ? new clp_03() : new clp_04()
    addChild(new_clp2)

var clp_index3 = parseInt(bmtd.text) >= parseInt(basketmtdtarget.text) ? 1 : 2
    var new_clp3 = clp_index3 == 1 ? new clp_05() : new clp_06()
    addChild(new_clp3)

}
```